# python script to move a file from GCP cloud storage to FHIR store regularly

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying a python script to move a file from GCP cloud storage to FHIR store regularly.
I am looking for an option with:
1>Cloud function
2>raw python script to schedule with cron job

any support is really appreciated.

Comment: Do not ask others to write or provide code. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. For some questions, code might be included in the answer. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I tried your use case and I managed to move the file from Cloud Storage to FHIR store with schedule by using `Cloud Functions`,`Cloud Storage`, `Cloud Scheduler` and `Cloud Healthcare API` services in GCP.

In `Cloud Function`, I used this [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/samples/healthcare-import-fhir-resources#code-sample) from the official documentation for importing **FHIR** resources from Cloud Storage. Just make sure you have installed the [dependencies](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/e0a3afe3fa5a635fbf7a823d29d318a44992dc14/healthcare/api-client/v1/fhir/requirements.txt) in order to run the code sample. Below is a sample code on my Cloud Functions. (**Note** that I use the Cloud function [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account))

**main.py**

```py
def hello_world(request):
  # Imports the Google API Discovery Service.
  from googleapiclient import discovery

  api_version = "v1"
  service_name = "healthcare"
  # Instantiates an authorized API client by discovering the Healthcare API
  # and using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
  client = discovery.build(service_name, api_version)

  # TODO(developer): Uncomment these lines and replace with your values.
  project_id = 'xxxx-xxxxx-'  # replace with your GCP project ID
  location = 'us-central1'  # replace with the parent dataset's location
  dataset_id = 'xxxxx-xxxxx'  # replace with the parent dataset's ID
  fhir_store_id = 'xxxx-xxxx'  # replace with the FHIR store ID
  gcs_uri = 'xxxx-xxxxx'  # replace with a Cloud Storage bucket
  fhir_store_parent = "projects/{}/locations/{}/datasets/{}".format(
      project_id, location, dataset_id
  )
  fhir_store_name = "{}/fhirStores/{}".format(fhir_store_parent, fhir_store_id)

  body = {
      "contentStructure": "CONTENT_STRUCTURE_UNSPECIFIED",
      "gcsSource": {"uri": "gs://{}".format(gcs_uri)},
  }

  # Escape "import()" method keyword because "import"
  # is a reserved keyword in Python
  request = (
      client.projects()
      .locations()
      .datasets()
      .fhirStores()
      .import_(name=fhir_store_name, body=body)
  )

  response = request.execute()
  print("Imported FHIR resources: {}".format(gcs_uri))

  print(response)
  return response
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-api-python-client==2.47.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth==2.6.2
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-storage==2.0.0; python_version < '3.7'
google-cloud-storage==2.1.0; python_version > '3.6'
```

Then create a `Cloud Scheduler` job by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#create). It depends on you on how you will [schedule your job](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules). Please note to choose **HTTP** as **target type** then paste the **Trigger url** of your Cloud function and choose **GET** HTTP method.

You may see if the import is successful in the **Healtcare Page -> Dataset ->  Operations Tab**.

Sample output:
[image]